# Effective Set up for a counterargument

Tags: phrases

Are there any extremely effective phrases that set up a counterargument well other than the standard "Skeptics may say" or anything of that nature? I feel like though phrases are heavily overused, but I can not think of any good phrases.

Comment: A phrase that used to be used all the time, but seems to be less so recently, is "contrary to popular belief". https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/contrary-to-popular-belief

Comment: 'I'm afraid I can't agree,' 'On the contrary, 'I believe that the gentleman has committed a terminological inexactitude,' 'Rubbish!' // 'It is a common conception that ....  However, there is evidence that is often overlooked that adherents to this philosophy have failed to explain satisfactorily.'

Answer (score 1):

https://www.is34.org/pdfs/Examples_of_Argumentative_Language.PDF

*Useful Argumentative Essay Words and Phrases*

---

https://writingcenter.fas.harvard.edu/pages/counter-argument

> The Turn Against
>
> Counterargument in an essay has two stages: you turn against your
>   argument to challenge it and then you turn back to re-affirm it. You
>   first imagine a skeptical reader, or cite an actual source, who might
>   resist your argument by pointing out:
>
> a problem with your demonstration, e.g., that a different conclusion
>   could be drawn from the same facts, a key assumption is unwarranted, a
>   key term is used unfairly, certain evidence is ignored or played down;
>   one or more disadvantages or practical drawbacks to what you propose;
>   an alternative explanation or proposal that makes more sense.